# Issues using MongoDB with a lot of data to insert

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

We have issues using MongoDB with a lot of data to insert.

In this case exists web socket clients connected to WebSocket (Socket.IO).
These clients generate an event log each 10 seconds and send it as WebSocket events.
The WebSocket receive the event and write that on MongoDB.

We have something like 6000 web socket clients connected sending this event logs.
The 6000 clients generate 600 event logs per second or more because some clients store offline data to transfer after connect.

We have one database per customer account and one collection to store this documents.

The document has this content:

```
{
  “_id”: “1k2jh3k2h31kh1…",
  “clientId": 1,
  “mediaId": 2,
  “createdAt": “2018-12-05 11:00:00”,
  "type": “I"
}
```

The document have a key unique using 3 attributes: clientId, mediaId and createdAt.

Also we have a web interface to generate reports with aggregation for key attributes.
And the aggregation is heavy and very slow.

Currently we use a EC2 large instances running MongoDB.
But we have a lot overload issues on MongoDB.

And we have plans to increase the operations to 20.000 clients.

My question is: MongoDB is the best solution for this use case? What is the best practices to work with a lot of data to insert and aggregation reports?

Comment: Maybe this question is too broad.

Comment: @JeroenHeier maybe yes.
My main question: Is a good solution MongoDB for that insert volume data and aggregation after for reports?